# Initial thread data chance?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm still somewhat new to threads and was wondering if I have an array of threads that get passed data from a loop.  Is there any chance that the initial data passed to that thread could change before the thread actually starts processing it?

```
const int TOTAL_THREADS = 32;
Thread[] _threadList = new Thread[TOTAL_THREADS];
List<class> OIDS = new List<class>();
OIDS.Add(new class());
...
...

for (int i = 0; i < OIDS.Count; i++)
{
    threadWait = true;
    while (threadWait == true)
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < TOTAL_THREADS; t++)
        {
            if (_threadList[t] == null || _threadList[t].IsAlive == false)
            {
                class oid = OIDS[i];
                _threadList[t] = new Thread(() => Worder.ProcessData(oid);
                _threadList[t].Start();
                threadWait = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (threadWait == true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mutate the data in oids, and with this code, then there is every chance the data will change before a thread processes it

Comment: Also, for your own sanity, i would use the newer `Task` class instead of the `Thread` class.

Comment: Does your code compile? I don't believe you can have a type named `class`. If you need a type with that name, you'll have to name it `@class`

Comment: Thanks @TheGeneral, I'll look into the Task class

Comment: @Flydog57 - no, it wont compile, the 'class' just just to signify it was a class in the list and not some basic datatype

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to replicate thread-coordination functionality that already exists in the platform, in various ways and forms. For example you could use the [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) class:

```
Parallel.ForEach(OIDS,
    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 32 },
    Worder.ProcessData);
```

This could be a valid approach if your workload is CPU based (you are doing calculations, not requests to a database or to the web), and the available cores of your machine are at least 32¹. It is also required that the processing of each element of the `OIDS` list is independent, or if it's not that you are synchronizing the dependencies inside the `Worder.ProcessData` by using [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)s or other means to prevent concurrent access to shared state.

(¹ This is an advice regarding the general case, not a hard assertion)

Comment: Saying `and the available cores of your machine are at least 32` is a very controversial statement. While there is certain correlation between `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and number of threads and potentially number of cores which can be utilized - they aren't the same. `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` indicates the upper limit of concurrent tasks while a thread can execute more than one task per its time slice if task is relatively small, or threads can contend and than making an oversubscription may allow to utilize CPU time better.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov so do you advise configuring the `Parallel.ForEach` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 32`, for a CPU-bound workload running in a machine with less that 32 cores? And if yes, under what conditions?

Comment: Actually my post wasn't to advise any specific value but just to highlight potentially incorrect assumption behind specific statement. That is having of N of cores doesn't automatically imply setting this parameter to N - this number can be higher in cases I mentioned above or lower when an algorithm doesn't imply to be scaled for example when it uses very specific number of tasks. In general case you shouldn't bother with setting this value at all, but rather use the default one.

Comment: And more precisely answering your question - when an algorithm implies contention and/or when an algorithm uses lightweight tasks when a thread can execute more than one.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov I specified explicitly the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` in my example, because of the line `const int TOTAL_THREADS = 32;` in OP's question. I think it was proper from me to hint that such a high degree of parallelism doesn't make sense without an equally large number of available cores. I agree with you that in some cases it may be beneficial to have a configuration with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` > available cores, but these cases should not come up very frequently.

Comment: You could specify in your example a value whatever you wanted and I do understand that it originated from the OP's question, my comment was about the `and the available cores of your machine are at least 32` statement part which sounds and looks like assertion while it isn't.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov you are right. I updated my answer to clarify this point.